# Marshalling data from a linq query into .NET object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a class called EventInfo:

```
public class EventInfo
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventDateRange { get; set; }
}
```

And using Entity Framework/linq to entity I would like to construct ab object of type EventInfo from the result of a LINQ command.

I have this:

```
using (var dataContext = new DataContext())
{
    var x =
        from event in dataContext.Events
        where event.EventID == 10
        select new EventInfo
        {
            EventName = event.ShowName,
            EventDateRange = $"{event.StartDate} - {event.EndDate}"
        };
}
```

However x is of type IQueryable[EventInfo] and I would need to do a .FirstOrDefault on it and check for null.

Is there a way to do this directly?

Comment: As in; you want to supply the default value within the LINQ query? Not sure what you are asking

Comment: What's wrong with calling `FirstOrDefault` if you need first event matching query?

Comment: You can do `var x = (from ... {...}).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: is your EF ok with interpolated string in expression?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
using (var dataContext = new DataContext())
{
    var x =(
        from event in dataContext.Events
        where event.EventID == 10
        select new EventInfo
        {
            EventName = event.ShowName,
            EventDateRange = $"{event.StartDate} - {event.EndDate}"
        }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: But when I return this I do not know if it is really an event or null/default

Comment: @andrewb Well yeah, you have to check it... what do you *want* it to do?

Comment: @andrewb when you run this query, you don't know whether there is matching record in your database. That's why you need `null` option for result

Comment: @andrewb you really don t know how to check if x is null? if(x== null){}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var dataContext = new DataContext())
{
    var x = dataContext.Events
        .Where(x => x.EventID == 10)
        .Select(x => new EventInfo()
        {
              EventName = x.Name,
              EventDateRange = $"{x.StartDate} - {x.EndDate}"
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

if (x == null) {
    // there was no result
}
else {
    // Result found, and x is EventInfo
}
```

Although, instead of checking x for null you might prefer just returning x to the caller, and then checking it for null and acting accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I went with something like this, however the EventDateRange assign line throws error related to the formatting.